# SVG Mouse Event Passthrough except for elements

Tags: javascript, svg, events, mouseevent, onmouseover

I have a transparent SVG canvas as an overlay to other elements. What I want is to allow mouse event pass through to the elements below, but events on the visible svg elements to also work. I can get it so the svg captures events, or lets them though with css pointer-events (none|auto) on the svg element, but can't work out how to capture events only on the visible elements of the svg.

I create the svg elements dynamically, e.g.

```
C=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","circle")
C.setAttributeNS(null,"r",curve_radius)
C.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",x)
C.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",y)
C.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb(0,0,255)")
C.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","rgb(0,0,255)")     
C.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-width","1")

svg.appendChild(C) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You found [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). I think it is just a matter of tweaking it in the right way. Here I "disable" pointer-events on the `<svg>` and at the same time specifying that the stroke of the `<circle>` should take event.

```js
document.getElementById('bg').addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e.target.nodeName);
});
```

```css
#bg {
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

svg {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
}

circle {
  pointer-events: stroke;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <p>Text</p>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="200">
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="red" fill="none"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```